# How to loop in javascript until condition is met and add the results to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I need to push two key/value pairs to an array based on the different conditions.

**Condition for the first key/value**: only paragraph starting with the number.

**Condition for the second key/value**: all paragraphs after the first key/value pair (until the next paragraph starting with number).

Here is the html example:

```
<div class="someclass">
    <p><strong>1. Some text</strong></p>
    <p>Some text related to 1.</p>
    <p>Some other <a href="/someurl"><strong> text</strong></a> related to 1.</p>
    <p><strong>2. Some other text</strong></p>
    <p>Some text related to 2.</p>
    <p><strong>3. Can you send me a catalog?</strong></p>
    ...
</div>
```

I am able to get only one paragraph for the second key/value pair with this javascript code:

```
var array = [];
var allParagraphs = document.querySelectorAll("someclass p");
for (i = 0; i < allParagraphs.length; i++) {
    if (/^\d/.test(allParagraphs[i].innerText) === true) {
        array.push({
            "key1": allParagraphs[i].innerText,
            "customText": {
                "key2": allParagraphs[i + 1].innerText
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The output I get is something like:

```
[{key1: "1. Some text", customText: {key2: "Some text related to 1."}},{key1: "2. Some text", customText: {key2: "Some text related to 2."}},{...}]
```

And I need to get something like this:

```
[{key1: "1. Some text", customText: {key2: "Some text related to 1. Some other text related to 1."}},{key1: "2. Some text", customText: {key2: "Some text related to 2."}},{...}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

You can filter out empty key2 if you need

```js
const vals = [...document.querySelectorAll(".someclass p")].reduce((acc, elem) => {
  const first = elem.firstChild;
  if (first.tagName === "STRONG" && first.textContent.match(/^\d+\./)) {
    acc.push({
      "key1": elem.textContent,
      "customtext": {
        "key2": [""]
      }
    })
  } else acc[acc.length - 1].customtext.key2[0] += elem.textContent;
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(vals)
```

```html
<div class="someclass">
  <p><strong>1. Some text</strong></p>
  <p>Some text related to 1.</p>
  <p>Some other <a href="/someurl"><strong> text</strong></a> related to 1.</p>
  <p><strong>2. Some other text</strong></p>
  <p>Some text related to 2.</p>
  <p><strong>3. Can you send me a catalog?</strong></p>
</div>
```

ES5

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll(".someclass p");
const acc = [];
for (let i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
  const first = elems[i].firstChild;
  if (first.tagName === "STRONG" && first.textContent.match(/^\d+\./)) {
    acc.push({
      "key1": elems[i].textContent,
      "customtext": {
        "key2": [""]
      }
    })
  } else acc[acc.length - 1].customtext.key2[0] += elems[i].textContent;
}

console.log(acc)
```

```html
<div class="someclass">
  <p><strong>1. Some text</strong></p>
  <p>Some text related to 1.</p>
  <p>Some other <a href="/someurl"><strong> text</strong></a> related to 1.</p>
  <p><strong>2. Some other text</strong></p>
  <p>Some text related to 2.</p>
  <p><strong>3. Can you send me a catalog?</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks like just what I needed, but now I am struggling getting it correct in EC5..

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that this:

```
for (i = 0; i < allParagraphs.length; i++) {
    if (/^\d/.test(allParagraphs[i].innerText) === true) {
```

Should be this:

```
for (i = 0; i < allParagraphs.length; i++) {
    while (/^\d/.test(allParagraphs[i].innerText) === true) {
```

Basically, the IF statement runs once and then proceeds to the next for loop, while the WHILE is running while the condition inthe parentheses is true